# List all sequences in a Postgres db 8.1 with SQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, migration, sequences

I'm converting a db from postgres to mysql.

Since i cannot find a tool that does the trick itself, i'm going to convert all postgres sequences to autoincrement ids in mysql with autoincrement value.

So, how can i list all sequences in a **Postgres** DB (**8.1** version) with information about the table in which it's used, the next value etc with a SQL query?

Be aware that i can't use the `information_schema.sequences` view in the 8.4 release.

Comment: It should be noted that you're doing the conversion the wrong way. Since Oracle bought Sun they've been slowly killing off MySQL so unless you despise your client (in which case you should simply quit) you should stick with PostgreSQL as no corporation (pro-monopoly of not) can come along, gobble up PostgreSQL and eventually replace it with their own database.

Comment: @John I'd say that there is a billion and one other reasons to stick with postgres, and a billion more to never touch mysql, but yes - your point is still very valid :)

Comment: @John at the time (2009) we need a simpler database to deal with - and mysql was better coupled to php

Answer (score 349, accepted):

The following query gives names of all sequences.

```
SELECT c.relname FROM pg_class c WHERE c.relkind = 'S' order BY c.relname;
```

Typically a sequence is named as `${table}_id_seq`. Simple regex pattern matching will give you the table name.

To get last value of a sequence use the following query:

```
SELECT last_value FROM test_id_seq;
```

Comment: The `${table}_id_seq` hint was useful

Comment: `${table}_${column}_seq` for auto-created sequences

Answer (score 136):

Note, that starting from PostgreSQL 8.4 you can get **all** information about sequences used in the database via:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.sequences;
```

---

Since I'm using a higher version of PostgreSQL (9.1), and was searching for same answer high and low, I added this answer for posterity's sake and for future searchers.

Comment: Protip: sort the answers by "active". Posterity gets more and more relevant as questions are becoming increasingly old..

Comment: Cool. And it looks like if I pick the "active" sorting method, the site just remembers the setting right away (here I was digging around in preferences to find a place to set it as default to no avail). Hm, now if only we had a "asker-accepted answer doesn't automatically trump everything else"-option, *that* would be a truly _great_ victory for posterity.

Comment: Note sure this table was introduced in PG 8.4, I'd rather say PG 8.2 after the official documentation : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/infoschema-sequences.html

Comment: That "all information" doesn't  include the current value.

Comment: true, you still have to use `SELECT last_value FROM <sequence_name>` to get that.  This answer shows the schema of the sequence which is what I needed to filter on and something that is not available with the `pg_class` view.

Answer (score 74):

Launch `psql` with the `-E` flag ("echo the actual queries generated by `\d` and other backslash commands"), then enter the `\ds` command to list all sequences. You should see something like this:

```
# \ds
********* QUERY **********
SELECT n.nspname as "Schema",
  c.relname as "Name",
  CASE c.relkind WHEN 'r' THEN 'table' WHEN 'v' THEN 'view' WHEN 'm' THEN 'materialized view' WHEN 'i' THEN 'index' WHEN 'S' THEN 'sequence' WHEN 's' THEN 'special' WHEN 'f' THEN 'foreign table' WHEN 'p' THEN 'partitioned table' WHEN 'I' THEN 'partitioned index' END as "Type",
  pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(c.relowner) as "Owner"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
     LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
WHERE c.relkind IN ('S','')
      AND n.nspname <> 'pg_catalog'
      AND n.nspname <> 'information_schema'
      AND n.nspname !~ '^pg_toast'
  AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid)
ORDER BY 1,2;
**************************

                     List of relations
 Schema |              Name              |   Type   | Owner 
--------+--------------------------------+----------+-------
 public | assignments_id_seq             | sequence | root
 public | framework_users_id_seq         | sequence | root
 public | lending_items_id_seq           | sequence | root
 public | proxy_borrower_requests_id_seq | sequence | root
 public | roles_id_seq                   | sequence | root
 public | stack_requests_id_seq          | sequence | root
(6 rows)
```

To examine a particular sequence, you can then run `\d <sequence name>`:

```
# \d lending_items_id_seq
********* QUERY **********

(...about four queries...)

**************************

                    Sequence "public.lending_items_id_seq"
  Type  | Start | Minimum |       Maximum       | Increment | Cycles? | Cache 
--------+-------+---------+---------------------+-----------+---------+-------
 bigint |     1 |       1 | 9223372036854775807 |         1 | no      |     1
Owned by: public.lending_items.id
```

Comment: i don't need only the list of sequences, i need the table in which it's used, the next value etc..

And i have to do that in SQL

Comment: Then, on every sequence do \d <name> (being still in psql -E)

Comment: again, this is not in SQL and doesn't show at which table the sequence is attached

Comment: @avastreg: did you run it the way i told you to? and why not?

Comment: @avastreg: It seems you did not try the suggestion, because it will show you exactly the SQL you need.

Comment: i need to do that directly with SQL statements! i can't use command line

Comment: @avastreg: JUST DO IT *ONCE*. And it will show you the queries!

Comment: sorry only now i understand what you meant!

Answer (score 36):

after a little bit of pain, i got it.

the best way to achieve this is to list all tables

```
select * from pg_tables where schemaname = '<schema_name>'
```

and then, for each table, list all columns with attributes

```
select * from information_schema.columns where table_name = '<table_name>'
```

then, for each column, test if it has a sequence

```
select pg_get_serial_sequence('<table_name>', '<column_name>')
```

and then, get the information about this sequence

```
select * from <sequence_name>
```

Answer (score 18):

sequence info : max value

`SELECT * FROM information_schema.sequences;`

sequence info : last value

`SELECT * FROM <sequence_name>`

Answer (score 14):

Get all sequence:

```
select * from pg_sequences;
```

PSQL:

```
\ds
\ds+
\ds *actor*
```

`\ds *actor*` will get all the sequence that sequence name contains *actor* characters.

Answer (score 12):

The relationship between automatically generated sequences ( such as those created for SERIAL columns ) and the parent table is modelled by the sequence owner attribute.

You can modify this relationship using the OWNED BY clause of the [ALTER SEQUENCE commmand](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-altersequence.html)

e.g. 
     ALTER SEQUENCE foo_id OWNED by foo_schema.foo_table

to set it to be linked to the table foo_table

or
     ALTER SEQUENCE foo_id OWNED by NONE

to break the connection between the sequence and any table

The information about this relationship is stored in the [pg_depend catalogue table](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/catalog-pg-depend.html).

the joining relationship is the link between pg_depend.objid -> pg_class.oid WHERE relkind = 'S'  - which links the sequence to the join record and then pg_depend.refobjid -> pg_class.oid WHERE relkind = 'r' , which links the join record to the owning relation ( table )

This query returns all the sequence -> table dependencies in a database. The where clause filters it to only include auto generated relationships, which restricts it to only display sequences created by SERIAL typed columns.

```
WITH fq_objects AS (SELECT c.oid,n.nspname || '.' ||c.relname AS fqname , 
                           c.relkind, c.relname AS relation 
                    FROM pg_class c JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace ),

     sequences AS (SELECT oid,fqname FROM fq_objects WHERE relkind = 'S'),  
     tables    AS (SELECT oid, fqname FROM fq_objects WHERE relkind = 'r' )  
SELECT
       s.fqname AS sequence, 
       '->' as depends, 
       t.fqname AS table 
FROM 
     pg_depend d JOIN sequences s ON s.oid = d.objid  
                 JOIN tables t ON t.oid = d.refobjid  
WHERE 
     d.deptype = 'a' ;
```

Comment: Useful explanation of dependencies between tables & sequences. But your query found **not all sequences** for me. It seems that some sequences are exists without any dependencies.

Comment: yes, this query is explicitly only demonstrating sequences that are defined by database serial column definitions. This is explained in the answer.

Answer (score 8):

I know this post is pretty old, but I found the solution by [CMS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/28532/cms) to be very useful as I was looking for an automated way to link a sequence to the table AND column, and wanted to share.  The use of [pg_depend](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/catalog-pg-depend.html) catalog table was the key.  I expanded what was done to:

```
WITH fq_objects AS (SELECT c.oid,n.nspname || '.' ||c.relname AS fqname ,
                           c.relkind, c.relname AS relation
                    FROM pg_class c JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace ),

     sequences AS (SELECT oid,fqname FROM fq_objects WHERE relkind = 'S'),
     tables    AS (SELECT oid, fqname FROM fq_objects WHERE relkind = 'r' )
SELECT
       s.fqname AS sequence,
       '->' as depends,
       t.fqname AS table,
       a.attname AS column
FROM
     pg_depend d JOIN sequences s ON s.oid = d.objid
                 JOIN tables t ON t.oid = d.refobjid
                 JOIN pg_attribute a ON a.attrelid = d.refobjid and a.attnum = d.refobjsubid
WHERE
     d.deptype = 'a' ;
```

This version adds column to the list of fields returned.  With both the table name and the column name in hand, a call to [pg_set_serial_sequence](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-info.html) makes it easy to ensure that all sequences in the database are set correctly.  For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.reset_sequence(tablename text, columnname text)
 RETURNS void
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
    _sql VARCHAR := '';
BEGIN
    _sql := $$SELECT setval( pg_get_serial_sequence('$$ || tablename || $$', '$$ || columnname || $$'), (SELECT COALESCE(MAX($$ || columnname || $$),1) FROM $$ || tablename || $$), true)$$;
    EXECUTE _sql;
END;
$function$;
```

Hope this helps someone with resetting sequences!

Comment: a few years on,  I notice your update, and pop by to give an upvote :-)

Comment: Thanks @cms.  I still use this today.

Answer (score 8):

I know the question was about postgresql version 8 but I wrote this simple way here for people who want to get sequences in version 10 and upper

you can use the bellow query

```
select * from pg_sequences
```

[view-pg-sequences](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/view-pg-sequences.html)

Answer (score 4):

This statement lists the table and column that is associated with each sequence:

Code:

```
    SELECT t.relname as related_table, 
           a.attname as related_column,
           s.relname as sequence_name
    FROM pg_class s 
      JOIN pg_depend d ON d.objid = s.oid 
      JOIN pg_class t ON d.objid = s.oid AND d.refobjid = t.oid 
      JOIN pg_attribute a ON (d.refobjid, d.refobjsubid) = (a.attrelid, a.attnum)
      JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = s.relnamespace 
    WHERE s.relkind     = 'S' 

  AND n.nspname     = 'public'
```

more see here [link to answer](http://www.dbforums.com/showthread.php?1667561-How-to-list-sequences-and-the-columns-by-SQL&s=7c5a84b7489cc1d0f329262b4d4b83b8&p=6508623#post6508623)

Answer (score 2):

Improvement of the previous answer:

```
select string_agg('select sequence_name, last_value from ' || relname, chr(13) || 'union' || chr(13) order by relname) 
from pg_class where relkind ='S'
```

Comment: Please don't just put your code without any explanation. Also, since you've stated that your code is an "Improvement of the previous answer", you should also tell us WHY it is an improvement. Oh, don't give up, and welcome to SO!

Comment: Should I write a page of senseless text instead of precise code (couple of lines)?

Comment: Never said that. I like simple, precise code. But when stating that your code is an improvement, one or two lines explaining WHY it is an improvement (better readability, improved performance, etc) would not hurt. And you'd probably get a +1 from me as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
select sequence_name, (xpath('/row/last_value/text()', xml_count))[1]::text::int as last_value
from (
    select sequence_schema,
            sequence_name,         
            query_to_xml(format('select last_value from %I.%I', sequence_schema, sequence_name), false, true, '') as xml_count
    from information_schema.sequences
    where sequence_schema = 'public'
) new_table order by last_value desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

Partially tested but looks mostly complete.

```
select *
  from (select n.nspname,c.relname,
               (select substring(pg_catalog.pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid) for 128)
                  from pg_catalog.pg_attrdef d
                 where d.adrelid=a.attrelid
                   and d.adnum=a.attnum
                   and a.atthasdef) as def
          from pg_class c, pg_attribute a, pg_namespace n
         where c.relkind='r'
           and c.oid=a.attrelid
           and n.oid=c.relnamespace
           and a.atthasdef
           and a.atttypid=20) x
 where x.def ~ '^nextval'
 order by nspname,relname;
```

Credit where credit is due... it's partly reverse engineered from the SQL logged from a \d on a known table that had a sequence.  I'm sure it could be cleaner too, but hey, performance wasn't a concern.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of a hack, but try this:

```
select 'select ''' || relname  || ''' as sequence, last_value from '  || relname || '  union'
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
WHERE c.relkind IN ('S','');
```

Remove the last UNION and execute the result

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help.

Here is the pl/pgsql function which update each sequence of a database.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--- Nom : reset_sequence
--- Description : Générique - met à jour les séquences au max de l'identifiant
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION reset_sequence() RETURNS void AS 
$BODY$
DECLARE _sql VARCHAR := '';
DECLARE result threecol%rowtype; 
BEGIN
FOR result IN 
WITH fq_objects AS (SELECT c.oid,n.nspname || '.' ||c.relname AS fqname ,c.relkind, c.relname AS relation FROM pg_class c JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace ),
    sequences AS (SELECT oid,fqname FROM fq_objects WHERE relkind = 'S'),
    tables    AS (SELECT oid, fqname FROM fq_objects WHERE relkind = 'r' )
SELECT
       s.fqname AS sequence,
       t.fqname AS table,
       a.attname AS column
FROM
     pg_depend d JOIN sequences s ON s.oid = d.objid
                 JOIN tables t ON t.oid = d.refobjid
                 JOIN pg_attribute a ON a.attrelid = d.refobjid and a.attnum = d.refobjsubid
WHERE
     d.deptype = 'a' 
LOOP
     EXECUTE 'SELECT setval('''||result.col1||''', COALESCE((SELECT MAX('||result.col3||')+1 FROM '||result.col2||'), 1), false);';
END LOOP;
END;$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT * FROM reset_sequence();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another one which has the schema name beside the sequence name

```
select nspname,relname from pg_class c join pg_namespace n on c.relnamespace=n.oid where relkind = 'S' order by nspname
```

Answer (score 1):

Get sequences by each column of each table via parsing of DEFAULT clause. This method provides **info about to which column sequences are linked** and does not use [dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11630002/7573844) which may not exist for some sequences. Even `pg_get_serial_sequence(sch.nspname||'.'||tbl.relname, col.attname)` function found *not all* sequences for me!

Solution:

```
SELECT
    seq_sch.nspname  AS sequence_schema
  , seq.relname      AS sequence_name
  , seq_use."schema" AS used_in_schema
  , seq_use."table"  AS used_in_table
  , seq_use."column" AS used_in_column
FROM pg_class seq
  INNER JOIN pg_namespace seq_sch ON seq_sch.oid = seq.relnamespace
  LEFT JOIN (
              SELECT
                  sch.nspname AS "schema"
                , tbl.relname AS "table"
                , col.attname AS "column"
                , regexp_split_to_array(
                      TRIM(LEADING 'nextval(''' FROM
                           TRIM(TRAILING '''::regclass)' FROM
                                pg_get_expr(def.adbin, tbl.oid, TRUE)
                           )
                      )
                      , '\.'
                  )           AS column_sequence
              FROM pg_class tbl --the table
                INNER JOIN pg_namespace sch ON sch.oid = tbl.relnamespace
                --schema
                INNER JOIN pg_attribute col ON col.attrelid = tbl.oid
                --columns
                INNER JOIN pg_attrdef def ON (def.adrelid = tbl.oid AND def.adnum = col.attnum) --default values for columns
              WHERE tbl.relkind = 'r' --regular relations (tables) only
                    AND col.attnum > 0 --regular columns only
                    AND def.adsrc LIKE 'nextval(%)' --sequences only
            ) seq_use ON (seq_use.column_sequence [1] = seq_sch.nspname AND seq_use.column_sequence [2] = seq.relname)
WHERE seq.relkind = 'S' --sequences only
ORDER BY sequence_schema, sequence_name;
```

Note that 1 sequence can be used in multiple tables, so it can be listed in multiple rows here.

Answer (score 1):

This function shows the last_value of each sequence.

It outputs a 2 columns table that says the sequence name plus it's last generated value.

```
drop function if exists public.show_sequence_stats();
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.show_sequence_stats()
    RETURNS TABLE(tablename text, last_value bigint) 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
    ROWS 1000
AS $BODY$
declare r refcursor; rec record; dynamic_query varchar;
        BEGIN
            dynamic_query='select tablename,last_value from (';
            open r for execute 'select nspname,relname from pg_class c join pg_namespace n on c.relnamespace=n.oid where relkind = ''S'' order by nspname'; 
            fetch next from r into rec;
            while found 
            loop
                dynamic_query=dynamic_query || 'select '''|| rec.nspname || '.' || rec.relname ||''' "tablename",last_value from ' || rec.nspname || '.' || rec.relname || ' union all ';
                fetch next from r into rec; 
            end loop;
            close r; 
            dynamic_query=rtrim(dynamic_query,'union all') || ') x order by last_value desc;';
            return query execute dynamic_query;
        END;
$BODY$;

select * from show_sequence_stats();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `exec()` function declared in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/46721603/653539 , sequences together with their last values can be fetched using single query:

```
select s.sequence_schema, s.sequence_name,
  (select * from exec('select last_value from ' || s.sequence_schema || '.' || s.sequence_name) as e(lv bigint)) last_value
from information_schema.sequences s
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how to use `psql` to get a list of all sequences with their `last_value`:

`psql -U <username> -d <database> -t -c "SELECT 'SELECT ''' || c.relname || ''' as sequence_name, last_value FROM ' || c.relname || ';' FROM pg_class c WHERE (c.relkind = 'S')" | psql -U <username> -d <database> -t`

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT nextval(sequence_schema || '.' || sequence_name)
FROM information_schema.sequences
```