# Reset auto increment counter in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, auto-increment, reset

I would like to force the auto increment field of a table to some value, unfortunately my query seems to fail

```
ALTER SEQUENCE categories_categoryid_seq RESTART WITH 1;
ERROR:  relation "your_sequence_name" does not exist
```

My table `categories` has the following columns:

- categoryid
- functions
- name

Edit: my Create query:

```
-- Table: public.categories

-- DROP TABLE public.categories;

CREATE TABLE public.categories
(
    categoryid bigint NOT NULL,
    functions character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    name character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT categories_pkey PRIMARY KEY (categoryid)
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.categories
    OWNER to postgres;
```

Comment: are you sure it's the name of the sequence? have you checked it with pgAdmin or similar tools? if not, try [to check it with a query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493262/list-all-sequences-in-a-postgres-db-8-1-with-sql)

Comment: prepend schema...

Comment: Yea, pgadmin is open. As an example the following query works perfectly: SELECT * FROM public.categories
ORDER BY categoryid
ASC

Comment: Apparently there is no sequence with that name. [edit] your question and show us the **complete** `create table` statement for `categories` and the `create` statement for the sequence.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I've added the create statement.

Comment: there's no `CREATE sequence`... and you don't use `bigserial` for `categoryid `

Comment: The column is defined without a default value and not as a `serial`. Why do you expect the sequence to exist in the first place? (Also: limiting a varchar to 255 character has no performance or storage advantages at all. 255 is not some magic limit that enables faster processing)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Still a newb in this.. I'll dig deeper on it, thx for your answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no sequences is created in this above questions because you are not added serial or sequence :(as per script). bigint must be bigserial or serial.

If you want to check it the sequence is created or not run this script.

```
Select column_default 
from information_schema.columns 
where table_name = 'categories' and column_name = 'categoryid';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can verify the name sequence defined in the `DEFAULT` clause:

```
SELECT column_name, column_default
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'myschema'
   AND table_name = 'categories'
ORDER BY ordinal_position;
```

Then you'll know which sequence to reset!

Comment: with the following query: FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE table_name = 'categories'
  AND column_name LIKE 'categoryid' I got my result: categoryid but still...  the sequence is not correct

Comment: @user3657270 the important information is in the `column_default` column. What do you get there?