# Postgres: Understanding Primary Key Sequences

Tags: postgresql, primary-key

My database has fallen out of sync, which lead me to this question:
[How to reset postgres' primary key sequence when it falls out of sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244243/how-to-reset-postgres-primary-key-sequence-when-it-falls-out-of-sync) (Copied Below)

However, I don't quite understand some things here: What is `'your_table_id_seq'`? I have no clue where to find this. Doing some digging, I found a table called `pg_sequence`
 in `pg_catalog`. Is it related to this? I can't see any way to relate that data back to my table though.

```
-- Login to psql and run the following

-- What is the result?
SELECT MAX(id) FROM your_table;

-- Then run...
-- This should be higher than the last result.
SELECT nextval('your_table_id_seq');

-- If it's not higher... run this set the sequence last to your highest id. 
-- (wise to run a quick pg_dump first...)

BEGIN;
-- protect against concurrent inserts while you update the counter
LOCK TABLE your_table IN EXCLUSIVE MODE;
-- Update the sequence
SELECT setval('your_table_id_seq', COALESCE((SELECT MAX(id)+1 FROM your_table), 1), false);
COMMIT;
```

Comment: In psql do `\d your_table` to see the sequence associated with it (if any). It should be the default entry of your PK column.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List all sequences in a Postgres db 8.1 with SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493262/list-all-sequences-in-a-postgres-db-8-1-with-sql)

Answer (score 0):

The following query gives names of all sequences.

```
SELECT c.relname 
FROM pg_class c 
WHERE c.relkind = 'S';
```

Typically a sequence is named as ${table}_id_seq.

I found the answer in this question: [List all sequences in a Postgres db 8.1 with SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493262/list-all-sequences-in-a-postgres-db-8-1-with-sql)

Comment: The question is a duplicate, flag/vote it as such, don't answer it.